# Comments for nested selectors don't appear where expected

Tags: sass, comments

Following is my SCSS file and its output. But when you check the compiled comments all are misplaced.

**SCSS**

```
/* Navigation */
.navigation{
   background: red;
   /*Subnavigation 1*/
  .subnav{
     background: #FFF;
   }
   /*Subnavigation 2*/
   .subnav2{
      background: black;
   }
 }
```

**Output**

```
/* Navigation */
.navigation {
  background: red;
  /*Subnavigation 1*/
  /*Subnavigation 2*/
}

.navigation .subnav {
  background: #FFF;
}

.navigation .subnav2 {
   background: black;
}
```

**Desired output**

```
/* Navigation */
.navigation {
  background: red;
}
/*Subnavigation 1*/
.navigation .subnav {
  background: #FFF;
}
/*Subnavigation 2*/
.navigation .subnav2 {
   background: black;
}
```

Is it a bug or issue with SCSS?. I'm using Compass 0.12.2 (Alnilam).

Comment: The comments are on the same nesting level as the properties for the `.navigation` class, so they are seen as belonging to that class rather than its children.

Comment: Yes, but is there anyway to correct it? We can't avoid nesting of subnav inside .navigation. The above code is a simple representation  of a complex nested style we have. Currently working on a theme based site and required this sort of nesting.

Comment: Your only option is to not nest.

Comment: All production CSS should be minified with comments removed. If it looks how you want in the SCSS that you're actually editing, why does it matter how it looks in the outputted CSS?

Comment: In production we are removing the comments and minifies css. But we have an intermediary stage where all code QA and css selector tests are being carried out by third party. Its important to give hint to them.

Answer (score 1):

suggestion:

change your comments standard.   instead of

```
/* Navigation */
.navigation{
   background: red;
   /*Subnavigation 1*/
  .subnav{
     background: #FFF;
   }
   /*Subnavigation 2*/
   .subnav2{
      background: black;
   }
 }
```

put the comments inside of the opening of the block:

```
.test {/*nav*/
    background: red;

    .test2{ /*subnavigation 1*/
    background:#fff;
    }

    .test3 {/*subnavigation 2*/
        background:#fff;
     }
 }
```

and you get the following output:

```
/* line 27, ../scss/main.scss */
.test {
  /*nav*/
  background: red;
}
/* line 30, ../scss/main.scss */
.test .test2 {
  /*subnavigation 1*/
  background: #fff;
}
 /* line 34, ../scss/main.scss */
 .test .test3 {
 /*subnavigation 2*/
     background: #fff;
}
```

would that work for your needs?

Comment: Thanks but this won't work. Now the comment relates to the property beneath  it. eg: /*nav*/ -> background:red. Thats not correct. Also if you have noticed .test { /*nav*/ is in a single line in code but in out put its push to next line. Both my issue and comment is not aligning correctly (above issue) are in scss github issue list.

(1) https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/735 


(2) https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/235

Answer (score 1):

You need to either [move comments into the block `{}` they belong to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16432161/822138) or write them without the nested syntax.

Consider

```
/* Navigation */
.navigation{
   background: red;
   /* TODO add a background image */
  .subnav{
     background: #FFF;
   }
}
```

In that case you probably don't want

```
/* TODO pick a better red */
.subnav{
    background: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loud comment to keep comments where you put them when Compass compiles:

```
/*! This comment isn't going anywhere. */
```

Comment: That will just prevent the minifier from removing the comment.